# Mule 4/DW 2.0/postgresql

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

I need help with fixing the error message posted below (Can't infer the SQL type to use for an instance of java.util.ArrayList. Use setObject() with an explicit Types value to specify the type to use.) The input payload seems to be all string data types. But why does Mule 4 or postgresql think they are Arraylist?

Input payload:

```
  {
    "show_id": "DPT",
    "audio": "English,Japanese",
    "genres": "Comedy,Romance",
    "genres_ids": "8,33",
    "original_language": "Japanese",
    "original_release_year": "2013",
    "quality_height": "1080",
    "quality_quality": "HD",
    "ratings": "PS,14,12,PG",
    "regions": "AU,IE,NZ,GB,US,CA"
  }
```

Database (postgresql) table:

```
show_id: varchar(10)
audio: varchar(100)
genres: varchar(100) 
genres_ids: bpchar(100)
original_language: varchar(100)
original_release_year: varchar(1000)
quality_height: varchar(1000)
quality_quality: varchar(2)
ratings: varchar(100)
regions: varchar(1000)
```

INSERT statement in Mule 4:

```
INSERT into catalog_information_daily_dev(show_id,audio,genres,genres_ids,original_language,original_release_year,quality_height,quality_quality,ratings,
regions) values("ABC",:audio,:genres,:genres_ids,:original_language,:original_release_year,:quality_height,
:quality_quality,:ratings,:regions)
```

Error Message:

> Can't infer the SQL type to use for an instance of java.util.ArrayList. Use setObject() with an explicit Types value to specify the type to use.

Comment: What is the question? Can you add more detail?

Comment: Need help with fixing the error message posted in my original post(Can't infer the SQL type to use for an instance of java.util.ArrayList. Use setObject() with an explicit Types value to specify the type to use.) The input payload seems to be all string data types. But why does Mule 4 or postgresql think they are Arraylist?

Comment: Please add more lines around the error message, there may be more details there. Also show the DB connector operation in the Mule XML and some lines around it for context. Some previous operation might be changing the payload.

Comment: Please also confirm your input parameters mapping as this might change how mule executes the sql statement (assuming the input payload you mentioned above is not the input parameter mapping).